# Quickly filter text with cli commands

Tags: text-processing, command-line

Sometimes I have output from a command line script that I would like to further process/filter with cli tools. I can't re-run the command because it takes a long time or will not produce the same output again.

Currently I paste the output into a new file in the text editor, save it and then use `cat` on cli to pipe it into tr, sed and other tools. This is cumbersome.

Is there a quicker way for such text processing tasks?

Comment: "I paste the output into a new file in the text editor, save it" - you could also the command for accessing the clipboard in your OS (e.g, `xclip` on Linux, `pbpaste` on macOS, etc.) to paste the the copied output directly into a file (`pbpaste > some-file`).

Comment: I don't know of any shell that would keep the output of the last command by default, but I think it should be possible to set up an `strace` background process tracking the output of your shell's child processes and make the last output available somehow.

Comment: as the command was already executed in the past and OP *can't re-run the command*, setting up *strace* would be useless; could help only with future executions of the command for which *tee* or piping to file is much better for text parsing purposes than *strace*

Comment: Making a shell that automatically saves the output of commands would be an interesting exercise, BUT a simplistic implementation would make the programs detect their stdout connected to a pipe instead of a terminal, which would affect the behaviour of many programs, and the output would be less than useful for e.g. ncurses programs that move the cursor around to redraw parts of the screen. Plus storing the output of someone's week-long Emacs session might also start being a bit unwieldy...

Comment: @magor The question is not about the command executed in the past, but about the same situation in the future. Starting a background process now will make the output available in all future, if the same situation happens again.

Comment: @Philippos the question is about a command which was executed in the past, as OP specified exactly that `I can't re-run the command`; and when i suggested OP to use `tee` or plan for the future if he needs the output, you didn't like that comment of mine either

Comment: *sigh*  The problem is: The OP doesn't know when the next time will be. It would help to add `|tee ...` to each command you type, but that's impractical. This has to run silently in background all the time, so for the next occasion when OP thinks »which I had redirected the ouput!«, the ouput is there in a temporary file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @muru I use a clipboard-to-shell tool now: `xsel`.

When I find that cli output needs to be mangled further, I select and copy it with ctrl+shift+c to the clipboard. Then I use `xsel -b` (= `xsel --clipboard`) to paste it as standard input to other tools:

```
$ xsel -b | grep foo | sed s/bar/baz/
```

This is solution that works everywhere without needing setup.

Answer (score 1):

You can do exactly the same thing as you describe, but without using a file, nor an editor. Just do not specify a filename as argument to the `cat` command. This means `cat` will read from stdin. Then, with the filter pipeline waiting, you just paste the text to the terminal, and press `CTRL-D` to close stdin for `cat`.

The drawback is that the filtered output is mingled with the input text. This does not hurt though if the filter stores the output into some file.

Answer (score 0):

Your use case is not specific enough, but if using Bash is not a problem, then you can benefit from [PROMPT COMMAND](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x264.html).

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='touch ~/.last_command_output; LAST_COMMAND_OUTPUT="$(cat ~/.last_command_output)"; exec >/dev/tty; exec > >(tee ~/.last_command_output)'
```

From now on you can work with `$LAST_COMMAND_OUTPUT` variable which should contain output from your last command.

What happens under the hood:

- `PROMPT_COMMAND` is a variable that defines command executed before BASH displays prompt (last command finished working in most of cases)
- `touch ~/.last_command_output;` - creates file `~/.last_command_output` so it will be used for storing purposes later on
- `LAST_COMMAND_OUTPUT="$(cat ~/.last_command_output)"` stores contents of the file mentioned before in environment variable named `LAST_COMMAND_OUTPUT` so using it is a matter of simple echo later
- `exec >/dev/tty;` - `exec` with no arguments is used to redirect output of current shell to `/dev/tty` (current terminal device) this is necessary to drop old redirection from previous command in terminal (see next bullet point)
- `exec > >(tee ~/.last_command_output)` - runs `tee` (it stores contents of stdin inside of file and also outputs it to stdout) using [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html) so exec can redirect output to this file descriptor that is like piping it to tee.

This seems a good place to start with. Then you probably could add some other features to it, like storing output from N last commands or making sure, that multiple sessions will not overwrite file used for storing output from command.

Also there are drawbacks. Redirecting output that way causes some commands notice that output is not stdout and you might experience different behaviour comparing to running in terminal without `PROMPT_COMMAND`. There might be only something like no color in terminal, but `ls` will output it's listing in one line instead of each entry line by line.
Most noticeable are problems with terminal programs that require input from user like `vi`. Warning that input is not a terminal and messed output in `$LAST_COMMAND_OUTPUT` variable.

Also, to disable this simply `unset PROMPT_COMMAND`.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the call to your existing command in a function like:

```
doit() {
    local ret=0

    exec 3>&1                           # save fd 1 (stdout) in fd 3 to restore later
    exec > >(tee output.txt)            # redirect stdout of this script to go to tee

    your_command "${@:--}"              # run whatever command you want

    ret="$?"                            # save that command's exit status

    exec 1>&3; 3>&-                     # restore stdout and close fd 3

    return "$ret"
}
```

then call `doit` instead of `your_command`. That will run `your_command` and save it's output in the file `output.txt` for editing later. Obviously name the function and output file something appropriate.